# sharing resources in remote sessions, macros

Tags: macros, sas, remote-access

I have compiled a macro on my local machine and would like to call that macro on my remote session using the `INHERITLIB` option.

I did the following way:

```
%macro prin(dataset);

proc print data=&dataset; 
run;
%mend;


proc catalog c=work.sasmacr et=macro;  
  copy out=sharemac.sasmacr;  
  select prin;  
quit;

libname sharemac "Z:\";


rsubmit wait=no inheritlib=(work=lwork sharemac=sharemac) ; 
options mstored sasmstore=sharemac; 
%prin(myhom.dd);
endrsubmit;
```

and now it throws a warning and stops compiling.
the warning is as below,

```
WARNING: Entry type MACRO not supported by CPORT.
```

what could be the error here?

Comment: Why would you want to copy the compiled macro? Why not just copy the source code and submit it to re-compile it on the remote machine?  Or just point both machines to the same autocall library of source code.

Comment: I don't think you can copy the compiled macro - it is machine code, it needs to be recompiled on each machine separately.

Comment: Not sure where CPORT comes into this.  Unless the INHERITLIB is somehow using CPORT under the hood?

Comment: @Tom It seems likely that it is.  I figured it was either CPORT or UPLOAD, or perhaps both, under the hood.